# Add new row from partial view using jquery + Ajax MVC 4 .NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view which defines a row of a table as under:

```
@model CarpetApp.Models.OrderDetails
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("OrderDetails"))
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RunningNO)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectReference)</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DesignId, Model.design)</td>
        <td>Quality Dropdown List</td>
        <td>@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectBackGround, Model.BackGround)</td>
        <td>@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedMotif, Model.Motif)</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.measurement, Model.mesurements)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.WidthIntPart)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.WidthDecPart)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LengthInt)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LengthDec)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Area)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Remark)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Further, I am trying to load these rows into the following table:

```
<table id="tabletab" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Running No</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Project Ref</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Design</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Quality</th>
        <th colspan="2">Color</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Measurement Unit</th>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2">Width</th>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2">Length</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Area</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Remarks</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Background</th>
        <th>Motif</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am using Ajax calls to load the partial view:

```
         $(function () {
             $("#addAnother").click(function () {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 $.get('/Order/AddOrder', function (template) {
                     $("#tabletab").append(template);
                 });
             });
         });
```

However, the problem is that the partial view is bring returned through the Ajax call but does not align with the table columns defined in the view that calls the ajax function. Instead the result just loads in a single column.

I can similarly load html that is predefined in the ajax itself, and various solutions in the web exists for the same. However, I am not able to load the rows defined in the partial view above. Specifically loading the partial view using

```
@Html.Action("AddOrder")
```

however works as desired.

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my project. In the partial try putting the Begin Collection inside the `<tr>`.

```
<tr>
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("OrderDetails"))
   {
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RunningNO)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectReference)</td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DesignId, Model.design)</td>
    <td>Quality Dropdown List</td>
    <td>@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectBackGround, Model.BackGround)</td>
    <td>@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedMotif, Model.Motif)</td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.measurement, Model.mesurements)</td>         
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.WidthIntPart)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.WidthDecPart)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LengthInt)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LengthDec)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Area)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Remark)</td>}
</tr>
```

good luck